# Javascript even after bind can't access the variable

Tags: javascript, closures

I was trying to understand the closure but I was not getting how it can access the variable of a function that no longer exists.
So I wrote this.

```
function foo() {
    var from = 'from node';
    function func() {
        console.log('hello world', from);
    }
    func();
}
foo();
```

Output

```
node index.js
hello world from node
```

OK this is also working

Now what if I move the func to global scope

```
function func() {
    console.log('hello world', from);
}

function foo() {
    var from = 'from node';
    func();
}
foo();
```

And it didn't work as I thought.
What if I bind the **this** and then call
Like this

```
function func() {
    console.log('hello world', this.from);
}

function foo() {
    var from = 'from node';
    func.bind(this)();
}
foo();
```

According to me, this should work as I have explicitly given it this variable.

But it is still printing undefined which don't understand why.

Comment: That's a misuse of `this`. In the context of those functions, `this` is the global object (in a browser `this` is the window).

Comment: The first example isn't exactly a **closure**.

Comment: What I wanted to know that if it worked in the first case then why not in the last case.

Comment: I have created a closure example for you in both es6 / es5 it's here https://jsfiddle.net/961ej5pn/2/